Spark - How to read large zstandard file efficiently
I'm trying to read a large zstandard file (~30GB compressed) in Databricks with Spark. It's a collection of chess games in the following PGN format (.pgn.zst)
[Event "Rated Bullet tournament https://lichess.org/tournament/yc1WW2Ox"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/PpwPOZMq"]
[Date "2017.04.01"]
[Round "-"]
[White "Abbot"]
[Black "Costello"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2017.04.01"]
[UTCTime "11:32:01"]
[WhiteElo "2100"]
[BlackElo "2000"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-4"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+1"]
[WhiteTitle "FM"]
[ECO "B30"]
[Opening "Sicilian Defense: Old Sicilian"]
[TimeControl "300+0"]
[Termination "Time forfeit"]

1. e4 { [%eval 0.17] [%clk 0:00:30] } 1... c5 { [%eval 0.19] [%clk 0:00:30] }
2. Nf3 { [%eval 0.25] [%clk 0:00:29] } 2... Nc6 { [%eval 0.33] [%clk 0:00:30] }
3. Bc4 { [%eval -0.13] [%clk 0:00:28] } 3... e6 { [%eval -0.04] [%clk 0:00:30] }
4. c3 { [%eval -0.4] [%clk 0:00:27] } 4... b5? { [%eval 1.18] [%clk 0:00:30] }
5. Bb3?! { [%eval 0.21] [%clk 0:00:26] } 5... c4 { [%eval 0.32] [%clk 0:00:29] }
6. Bc2 { [%eval 0.2] [%clk 0:00:25] } 6... a5 { [%eval 0.6] [%clk 0:00:29] }
7. d4 { [%eval 0.29] [%clk 0:00:23] } 7... cxd3 { [%eval 0.6] [%clk 0:00:27] }
8. Qxd3 { [%eval 0.12] [%clk 0:00:22] } 8... Nf6 { [%eval 0.52] [%clk 0:00:26] }
9. e5 { [%eval 0.39] [%clk 0:00:21] } 9... Nd5 { [%eval 0.45] [%clk 0:00:25] }
10. Bg5?! { [%eval -0.44] [%clk 0:00:18] } 10... Qc7 { [%eval -0.12] [%clk 0:00:23] }
11. Nbd2?? { [%eval -3.15] [%clk 0:00:14] } 11... h6 { [%eval -2.99] [%clk 0:00:23] }
12. Bh4 { [%eval -3.0] [%clk 0:00:11] } 12... Ba6? { [%eval -0.12] [%clk 0:00:23] }
13. b3?? { [%eval -4.14] [%clk 0:00:02] } 13... Nf4? { [%eval -2.73] [%clk 0:00:21] } 0-1

To load the file, I am using spark.read.text. From my understanding, zst files are not splittable so this ends up reading the whole file into a single partition which causes massive spills. I also wanted to apply a pivot transformation to extract each games into a single record. I believe due to me having to go line by line grouping each rows into a game, this step also runs inefficiently on one partition as well.
I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this in Spark, and if not what is a more appropriate tool for a job like this?
Below is my code with a sample df for clarification
df = spark.read.text(file_name).filter(
    (col('value') != '') &
    (~col('value').like('%UTCTime%')) &
    (~col('value').like('%Result%'))
)




value




[Event "Rated Blitz game"]


[White "btr18am"]


[Black "Kozionov_sergey"]


...


[Opening "Queen's Gambit Declined: Exchange Variation, Positional Variation"]


1. d4 { [%clk 0:03:00] } d5 { [%clk 0:03:00] } 2. c4 { [%clk 0:03:01] } e6 { [%clk 0:03:01] } ...  27. Nxf7 { [%clk 0:01:28] } 1-0


[Event "Rated UltraBullet tournament https://lichess.org/tournament/5Emn5TK6"]


[White "rickyrich"]


[Black "seanysean"]


...


[Opening "Alekhine Defense"]


1. e4 { [%clk 0:00:15] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } 2. e5 { [%clk 0:00:14] } g6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } ... 22. Rxe1 { [%clk 0:00:00] } Bc3+ { [%clk 0:00:11] } 0-1



# Rename the "value" column to "Line"
df = df.withColumnRenamed("value", "Line")

# Extract the "Key" and "Value" columns based on the structure of the "Line" column
df = df.withColumn('Key', when(col('Line').startswith('1.'), 'Moves')
                   .otherwise(regexp_extract(col('Line'), r'\[(.*?)\s', 1))) \
       .withColumn('Value', when(col('Line').startswith('1.'), col('Line'))
                   .otherwise(regexp_extract(col('Line'), r'"(.*)"', 1)))

# Add a column to identify the start of a game
df = df.withColumn("StartOfGame", when(col("Line").startswith("[Event"), 1).otherwise(0))

# Define a window specification for calculating the cumulative sum
windowSpec = Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())

# Calculate the cumulative sum of "StartOfGame" to create "GameID"
df = df.withColumn("GameID", sum("StartOfGame").over(windowSpec))




Line
Key
Value
StartOfGame
GameID




[Event "Rated Blitz game"]
Event
Rated Blitz game
1
1


[White "btr18am"]
White
btr18am
0
1


[Black "Kozionov_sergey"]
Black
Kozionov_sergey
0
1


…
…
…
0
1


[Opening "Queen's Gambit Declined: Exchange Variation, Positional Variation"]
Opening
Queen's Gambit Declined: Exchange Variation, Positional Variation
0
1


1. d4 { [%clk 0:03:00] } d5 { [%clk 0:03:00] } 2. c4 { [%clk 0:03:01] } e6 { [%clk 0:03:01] } ...  27. Nxf7 { [%clk 0:01:28] } 1-0
Moves
1. d4 { [%clk 0:03:00] } d5 { [%clk 0:03:00] } 2. c4 { [%clk 0:03:01] } e6 { [%clk 0:03:01] } ...  27. Nxf7 { [%clk 0:01:28] } 1-0
0
1


[Event "Rated UltraBullet tournament https://lichess.org/tournament/5Emn5TK6"]
Event
Rated UltraBullet tournament https://lichess.org/tournament/5Emn5TK6
1
2


[White "rickyrich"]
White
rickyrich
0
2


[Black "seanysean"]
Black
seanysean
0
2


…
…
…
0
2


[Opening "Alekhine Defense"]
Opening
Alekhine Defense
0
2


1. e4 { [%clk 0:00:15] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } 2. e5 { [%clk 0:00:14] } g6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } ... 22. Rxe1 { [%clk 0:00:00] } Bc3+ { [%clk 0:00:11] } 0-1
Moves
1. e4 { [%clk 0:00:15] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } 2. e5 { [%clk 0:00:14] } g6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } ... 22. Rxe1 { [%clk 0:00:00] } Bc3+ { [%clk 0:00:11] } 0-1
0
2



# Define the list of columns for pivoting
col_list = [ 
    'UTCDate', 'Event', 'TimeControl', 'Opening', 'ECO' , 'Site',
     'Termination', 'Moves', 
    'White', 'WhiteTitle', 'WhiteElo', 'WhiteRatingDiff', 
    'Black', 'BlackTitle', 'BlackElo', 'BlackRatingDiff', 
    ]


# Pivot the DataFrame based on "GameID" and the specified columns
df = df.groupBy("GameID").pivot("Key", col_list).agg(first("Value"))

df = df.filter(col('Moves').contains('%eval'))

df.write.partitionBy('UTCDate').mode("overwrite").parquet(silver_file_path)




GameID
Event
White
Black
…
Opening
Moves




1
Rated Blitz game
btr18am
Kozionov_sergey
…
Queen's Gambit Declined: Exchange Variation, Positional Variation
1. d4 { [%clk 0:03:00] } d5 { [%clk 0:03:00] } 2. c4 { [%clk 0:03:01] } e6 { [%clk 0:03:01] } ...  27. Nxf7 { [%clk 0:01:28] } 1-0


2
Rated UltraBullet tournament https://lichess.org/tournament/5Emn5TK6
rickyrich
seanysean
…
Alekhine Defense
1. e4 { [%clk 0:00:15] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } 2. e5 { [%clk 0:00:14] } g6 { [%clk 0:00:15] } ... 22. Rxe1 { [%clk 0:00:00] } Bc3+ { [%clk 0:00:11] } 0-1



I have tried using a bigger cluster with more memory. While it does reduce spills, I'm not sure if this is a more 'efficient' way of doing this as it also increaes the number of cores in the cluster which are ultimately unsued.

If a sufficiently large disk is available, extract the zst file and save each game as single text file before processing it with Spark.
Step 1: Split the file
Take the compressed file and write each chess game into its own file in a directory called pgn:
import zstandard as zstd

with zstd.open(file_name, 'r') as f:
  current = ''
  for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if line.startswith('[Event'):
        if current != '':
          text_file = open(f"pgn/out_{i}.pgn", "w")
          text_file.write(current)
          text_file.close()
          current = ''    
    current = current + line
    if i % 100_000 == 0:
      print(f'line {i:8d}: {line}')
  text_file = open(f"pgn/out_last.pgn", "w")
  text_file.write(current)
  text_file.close()

Step 2: Create a Spark dataframe
Now read the whole directory pgn with Spark. As Spark can now see the different text files it can distribute the work of reading the many files to the whole cluster. The result is a dataframe with each row being one game.
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.text('pgn', wholetext=True)
df.show(vertical=True, truncate=False)

Using wholetext=True eliminates the need for the window and pivot operations. Now the parsing of each row can continue as already described in the question.
